# Filtering sections of data including the starting and ending lines- PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

**I have a text file that looks like this:**

```
Data I'm NOT looking for  
More data that doesn't matter  
Even more data that I don't

&Start/Finally the data I'm looking for  
&Data/More data that I need  
&Stop/I need this too  

&Start/Second batch of data I need  
&Data/I need this too 
&Stop/Okay now I'm done  
Ending that I don't need
```

**Here is what the output needs to be:**

**File1.txt**

```
&Start/Finally the data I'm looking for  
&Data/More data that I need   
&Stop/I need this too
```

**File2.txt**

```
&Start/Second batch of data I need  
&Data/I need this too 
&Stop/Okay now I'm done
```

I need to do this for every file in a folder (sometimes there will be multiple files that will need to be filtered.) The files names can be incrementing: ex. File1.txt, File2.txt, File3.txt.

This is what I have tried with no luck:

```powershell
ForEach-Object{
$text -join "`n" -split '(?ms)(?=^&START)' -match '^&START' | 
Out-File B:\PowerShell\$filename}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were pretty close: your code correctly extracted the paragraphs of interest, but intra-paragraph out-filtering of non-`&`-starting lines was missing, and you needed to write to *paragraph-specific* output files:

```
$text -join "`n" -split '(?m)(?=^&Start)' -match '^&Start' | 
  ForEach-Object { $ndx=0 } { $_ -split '\n' -match '^&' | Out-File "File$((++$ndx)).txt" }
```

This creates sequentially numbered files starting with `File1.txt` for every paragraph of interest.

---

To do it for every file in a folder, with output filenames using fixed naming scheme `File<n>` across all input files (and thus cumulative numbering):

```
Get-ChildItem -File . | ForEach-Object -Begin { $ndx=0 } -Process {
  (Get-Content -Raw $_) -split '(?m)(?=^&Start)' -match '^&Start' | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -split '\n' -match '^&' | Out-File "File$((++$ndx)).txt" }
}
```

---

To do it for every file in a folder, with output filenames based on the input filenames and numbering per input file (PSv4+, due to use of `-PipelineVariable`):

```
Get-ChildItem -File . -PipelineVariable File | ForEach-Object {
 (Get-Content -Raw $_) -split '(?m)(?=^&Start)' -match '^&Start' | 
  ForEach-Object {$ndx=0} { $_ -split '\n' -match '^&' | Out-File "$($File.Name)$((++$ndx)).txt" }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You post a second question (against the rules) and it was deleted but here is my quick answer for it. I hope it will help you and give you more sense how PS works:

```
$InputFile = "C:\temp\test\New folder (3)\File1.txt"

# get file content
$a=Get-Content $InputFile

# loop for every line in range 2 to last but one
for ($i=1; $i -lt ($a.count-1); $i++)
    {
    #geting string part between & and / , and construct output file name
    $OutFile = "$(Split-Path $InputFile)\$(($a[$i] -split '/')[0] -replace '&','').txt"

    $a[0]| Out-File $OutFile #creating output file and write first line in it
    $a[$i]| Out-File $OutFile -Append #write info line
    $a[-1]| Out-File $OutFile -Append #write last line
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know it was against the rules to post multiple questions on this forum. Sorry.

Comment: It is against rules to put question sounds like "I have apples and want pie". You need to be more verbose, to add your code and ask more specific, not general questions.

Comment: The above code works but will not input the last line of the the text file.

Comment: If the answer is helpful please up-vote it. 
The syntax is correct for your second question - how to split small files.  Also you can easily change it to works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 $i=0
 gci -path "C:\temp\ExplodeDir" -file | %{ (get-content -path $_.FullName -Raw).Replace("`r`n`r`n", ";").Replace("`r`n", "~").Split(";") | %{if ($_ -like "*Start*") {$i++; ($_ -split "~") | out-file "C:\temp\ResultFile\File$i.txt" }} }
```